# PHP Unicode String Extraction - How to split a string and store it into two variable on the basis of position of first non alphabetic character ?

Tags: php, string, split, preg-match, explode

I have a .txt file containing a list of thousands of English words along with their meaning in Urdu language. 
The file structure is below. Each line start with a word along with its translation in unicode characters.

dict.txt(encoding UTF-8)

```
 Sony     سونی (sōnī)
 South Ossetia   جنوبی اوسیتیا (janūbī osetiyā)
 flower (ur-Arab'کھلنا) (unicode'(kʰilnā))
 fly    اڑنا (uṛnā)
 fog    کوہرا (m) (kuhrā)
 .
 .
```

Note : There are no spaces in the right of word Sony,fly,fog etc i added them for clarity

so far i had done this ..

```
$file = fopen("dict.txt",'r');
if ($file) {
while($lines = fgets($file)){
    $word = '';
    $def = ' ';
  //want to extract "word" and its "definition" from $lines
  }
}
    fclose($file);
```

Now i want to split every line of file in two variables to store them in database as $word and $def to store them in database for further use.

I tired myself using preg_match() and list()+explode() but i am a kind of newbie to my solutions does not work.i also tired searching google but does not find a satisfactory answer.

what i want to do..

{

if found a alphabet other then a-z/A-Z and space break the sting;
store left part in variable $name and right part in $def..

}

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always `[english][urdu]([pronunciation])`, this should do quite well:

```
preg_match('/^([\w\s]+)([\W\s]+)\((.+)\)$/', $line, $matches);
echo "English: $matches[1], Urdu: $matches[2], pronunciation: $matches[3]";
```

`[\w\s]+` matches "word and space characters", `[\W\s]+` is "non-word and space characters" ("word" means A-Z and a few characters like _) and `.*` between parentheses is the rest. See http://rubular.com/r/eHUQFczLah

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$arr = array(
"Sony     سونی (sōnī)",
"South Ossetia   جنوبی اوسیتیا (janūbī osetiyā)",
"flower (ur-Arab'کھلنا) (unicode'(kʰilnā))",
"fly    اڑنا (uṛnā)",
"fog    کوہرا (m) (kuhrā)"
);

foreach($arr as $val) {
    $list = preg_split('/([\w\s]+)(.+)/', $val, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
    print_r($list);
}
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sony     
    [1] => سونی (sōnī)
)
Array
(
    [0] => South Ossetia   
    [1] => جنوبی اوسیتیا (janūbī osetiyā)
)
Array
(
    [0] => flower 
    [1] => (ur-Arab'کھلنا) (unicode'(kʰilnā))
)
Array
(
    [0] => fly    
    [1] => اڑنا (uṛnā)
)
Array
(
    [0] => fog    
    [1] => کوہرا (m) (kuhrā)
)
```

Comment: thanks u v.much sir .. i have not considered that data was in text file so i can copy paste in a php array

Comment: @AhtshamKhan: You can replace the foreach by a while loop on each record of a file. I did that foreach only for testing.